# 'ah' not listed when calling HTML::Mason::Request->new()

Tags: perl, apache, mason

I'm writing codes which are originally from http://modperlbook.org/html/B-18-1-Apache-Session-8212-Maintain-Session-State-Across.html to use session.

But I got an error as below:
    "
    The following parameter was passed in the call to HTML::Mason::Request->new() but was   not listed in the validation options: ah\n\nStack:\n
    "

When I looked at Request.pm, 
'ah' is in its doc part, but not in **PACKAGE**->valid_params. Do I use 'my $status = $ah->handle_request($r);' wrongly?

Oh, I'm using HTML:Mason 1.42-2, Apache2 and perl5.

Thanks,

Yang

Comment: Yes, it is likely that you are doing something wrong there. I tried concentrating on your avatar for half an hour, but for some reason my psychic powers are failing and the relevant line number doesn't want to enter my consciousness.

Comment: Thanks mate. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: The first thing is about the line to get the parser. The HTML::Mason::Parser has been already depreciated, and the new HTML::Mason:Interp looks either not accepting the 'parser' any more. I'm checking what I should patch for this one.

Comment: Forget the parser, it looks irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figure out what should be done.

When creating the object for 'new HTML::Mason::Interp', explicitly ask

'request_class => 'HTML::Mason::Request::ApacheHandler'.

The default 'HTML::Mason::Request' won't support 'ah', but the 'ApacheHandler' does.